# Any way to force Selenium to consider a page fully loaded, even when the browser has unfinished requests pending?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Environment:  Chrome v29, selenium driver 2.35, chromedriver 2.2

On several tests, written in Behat w/ Selenium driving, all visible elements on the page have loaded, and Speed Tracer shows no pending requests, but Sometimes the browser status bar says "Connecting", and selenium seems to be stuck waiting for that connection to complete (it never does).  Other times, the exact same page loads immediately and is processed immediately.

If you let the test sit, eventually things time out, and it goes no further.
If you manually click "stop" in the browser, then selenium starts working again, and the test completes without further issues.

Ideally, I'd love to figure out why these pages hang like this, but I'd be happy to settle for a way around it too, some sort of "give this page 10 seconds, and then consider it 'done".

Comment: I'd personally figure out why the page never loads. Chrome has a Networks tab in it's Developer Console that tells you what's loaded and what's executing. Use that and see if it sheds any light. Does the same thing happen at all manually visiting the browser **outside** of Selenium? Same thing happen with the `FirefoxDriver`?

Comment: The issue does occur outside of Selenium, and does not happen with Firefox (but FF falls down on other issues where chrome works, so swapping browsers just changes what problem is currently blocking me, rather than solving the issue).

Comment: In the Network tab, I can see a "GET" with a status of "(failed)", and a type of "Pending", for a third party ad server.  I had already tried to address this by setting the requested domain to 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we had similar issue in watir-webdriver. Because APIs like .click, .goto in watir does two things. It clicks on an element and wait for the page to load (document.readyState == "complete"), if the page does not load within certain duration defined by HTTP_TIMEOUT, it times out. 
If your page depends on lots of services and especially in test environments, if at-least one service is slow to respond, even if 99% of the page is loaded, click api will timeout.

Solution we have is to create an api say click_no_timeout under Watir Element class which will be exact same as click api, except it will rescue the timeout and do nothing.

Its up to the project code to handle the timeout in case its really a valid timeout. I think you can follow the same approach to selenium as well.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Arran, it is best to figure out the reason for page taking time to load. But as a workaround, you can use JSExecutor to do the click operation for page navigations. It still leaves you with an issue if the main landing page also takes time to load.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, after any interaction which causes a page to load, Selenium does not return control until the page is fully loaded